# SQL Queries Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm having trouble on some SQL Queries.
These are the tables:

```
CREATE table Person(
driver_id int not null,
name varchar(30) not null,
address varchar(30),
PRIMARY KEY (driver_id)
);

CREATE table Car(
license int not null,
model varchar(20) not null,
year int not null,
PRIMARY KEY(license)
);

CREATE table Accident(
report_number int not null,
date date not null,
location varchar(30),
PRIMARY KEY(report_number)
);

CREATE table Owns(
driver_id int not null,
license int not null,
FOREIGN KEY(driver_id) REFERENCES Person,
PRIMARY KEY(driver_id,license),
FOREIGN KEY(license) REFERENCES Car);
```

CREATE table Participated(
driver_id int not null,
license int not null,
report_number int not null,
damage_amount int not null,
PRIMARY KEY(driver_id,license,report_number),
FOREIGN KEY(driver_id) REFERENCES Person,
FOREIGN KEY(license) REFERENCES Car,
FOREIGN KEY(report_number) REFERENCES Accident );

I need to find the number of accidents where AUDI Cars are participated.
This is what I've done for this:

```
SELECT report_number
FROM Participated P 
INNER JOIN Car C
ON P.license = C.license
WHERE model = 'AUDI';
```

While in this one, I have to find the average damage amount for every car model, in all accidents happened after 01/01/2014 in Descending Order.

```
SELECT AVG(damage_amount)
FROM Participated P
INNER JOIN Accident A
ON P.report_number = A.report_number
WHERE NOT data IN ('2014/01/01')
ORDER BY data DESC;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What type of trouble are you running into?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney No results being showed

Comment: Which queries are not returning results? I noticed in the second query you have an aggregate function (ie, `AVG`) but I did not see a necessary `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out two problems:

- You are referring to the wrong column name, there is no column named
  "data", I think you mean "date"
- If you want to select all the rows which have date greater than
  '2014/01/01', then you need to this

So you need to do this :

```
SELECT AVG(damage_amount)
FROM Participated P
INNER JOIN Accident A
ON P.report_number = A.report_number
WHERE date>'2014/01/01'
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Comment: Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Column "Accident.date" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that it won't work on SQL-server, it will work on MySQL

Comment: I have no ideas about the difference between the syntax of SQL server and MySQL, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

To get count of accidents:

```
SELECT count(a.report_id)
FROM Accident a INNER JOIN Participated p ON a.report_id = p.report_id
INNER JOIN Car c ON p.license = c.license
WHERE c.model = 'AUDI'
```

To find model's average damage amount in 2014 till now.

```
SELECT c.model, AVG(p.damage_amount), a.date
FROM Accident a INNER JOIN Participated p ON a.report_id = p.report_id
INNER JOIN Car c ON p.license = c.license
WHERE NOT data >= '2014/01/01'
GROUP BY c.model
ORDER BY a.date DESC;
```

Comment: Only first works for me.

I'm having this error for the second:
Column "Accident.date" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @XhensB The error is instructing you that you must *order* the records from a column that your query is grouping by. By looking at the above query, `GROUP BY` is only grouping by the `c.model` column. By adding `a.date` within the `GROUP BY` should remove the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

With aggregate functions you need a GROUP BY clause, otherwise you get the aggregates for the entire table.

```
SELECT c.model,a.date,AVG(a.damage_amount)
FROM Participated P
INNER JOIN Accident A
ON P.report_number = A.report_number
INNER JOIN car c
ON p.license = c.license
WHERE date>'2014/01/01'
GROUP BY a.date,c.model
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

if you remove a.date, you get aggregates across the table for each model (you can leave the a.date in the where clause), and if you remove c.model, you will get the aggregate for all models by date.
Good luck